# Is it possible to keep peonies standing upright?

Tags: flowers, peonies, support

My peonies quickly drooped over and became quite unattractive.  Is there a way to keep them upright?  I'm not thrilled about the idea of putting in stakes for each plant if that's my only option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In future, you could use a tomato cage to support your flowers.  Place the cage before your peony starts putting out new growth in the spring and as the stems elongate, pull the leaves and flower stems through the gaps to make it look natural. You can also buy peony 'cones' (google it) which look a lot like tomato cages and plant support 'hoops'.